# Tango PCB Designer

Tags: pcb, design

i'm trying to run the old Tango PCB on a DOSBox, on windows 8.1. I did the same things to make it run that i did on windows 7, but it's not working on windows 8.1, have anyone tried to run Tango on 8.1? can you help me?

Comment: run a virtual machine/image of an older windows operating system.

Comment: There's no need to bring up virtual Windows. Just get DOS. It's a DOS application after all, isnt it?

Comment: DOSBox is a DOS virtual machine, but, unhaply it isn't working :S

Comment: VMWare can probably run it.

Comment: Is there a reason to do this? Your profile indicates you're on the younger end of the spectrum, so I doubt you're maintaining an old product. Why not use any one of the dozens of free EDA solutions?

Comment: I tried Proteus, Eagle and some open source CAD tools, but no one seems to be as easy to use (for me) as Tango. I've been using it on windows 7 (dosbox) for some time and i really don't want to use another tool to drawn, i have practice and my own library, and the kind of projects that i've been doing doesn't requires autoroating. That's basically why i want to keep using Tango :P

Answer (score 2):

I've used Tango - but that must have been over 12 years ago, and was probably on Windows XP. If it won't run on Win 8.1, I'd assume it is a 16 bit program.

Use Windows Explorer to open the folder that contains the program (tango.exe). Right-click the .exe file, and select Properties. A 16-bit program does not have a Version tab in this dialog box.

Windows 8.1 will not run a 16 bit program.

If this is the case, then you could install a Virtual Machine (look for *Oracle VM Virtual Box*), install Windows XP on it, and then install Tango on XP in the Virtual Box.

Answer (score 2):

I am running Tango Pcb on linux LXLE dosbox V0.74.
It works 100%. Can make Gerber plots and read them with Gerbview 7 that runs on windows 7. My old Tango produce gerber files in RS274D (separate aperture file needed for the old system.)
With Gerbview 7 you can xport that file as RS274x the new system.

Answer (score 0):

Tango runs very well in DosDox 0.74, even in Windows 10 64 bit.
See instructions at:
http://www.acdcelectronics.ro/tango_sch_pcb_win_7_english.pdf

Good luck!!

Comment: Welcome to EESS!! However, do note that you are answering a question that was posted more than 4 years ago.

Comment: Thanks Edgar! i am an old man and still using Tango PCB. This work in every PC and with DosBox this seems immortal :)